# What is the best way to make this code recursive

Tags: c#, recursion

I have to edit some code that has a proposedDate (as a DateTime object called minDate) and an array of blackout dates.    Given a proposed Date, it tries to see if this is valid (NOT a blackout dates).  If it is a blackout date, then keep checking the next day until you find a date that is not a valid checkout date.  The existing code looks like this

```
if ( blackoutDates.Contains(minDate))
        {
            minDate = minDate.AddDays(1);
            dateOffset = dateOffset + 1;
            if ( blackoutDates.Contains(minDate))
            {
                minDate = minDate.AddDays(1);
                dateOffset = dateOffset + 1;
                if (blackoutDates.Contains(minDate))
                {
                    minDate = minDate.AddDays(1);
                    dateOffset = dateOffset + 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

Clearly there is a repeated pattern here and I am trying to figure out the best way to clean up this code and make it elegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for recursion. You can do this in a loop.

```
while(blackoutDates.Contains(minData)){
  minData = minData.AddDays(1);
  ++dataOffset;
 }
```

I don't know what language is this, but check if there is already a standard API for doing what you need first.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't make it recursive.  I would make it a `while` loop:

```
while(blackoutDates.Contains(minDate))
{
    minDate = minDate.AddDays(1);
    dateOffset = dateOffset + 1;
}
```

Recursion can express loops, but looping constructs are usually clearer when used in the context they are designed for.  They also make it a bit simpler to reach data that is outside the scope of the loop than recursion does (specifically local variables).